# How to efficiently build a random String with a custom alphabet?

Tags: java, random

I have an alphabet with an amount of *c* characters and want to create random `String`s of length *n* with that alphabet.

*As an example*, let's say the alphabet consists of the letters `a-w` (so *c* = 23) and the generated `String`s should have a length of *n* = 67.

An intuitive but also naive approach to generate such a `String` could look like this:

```
String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw";
int c = alpha.length();
int n = 67;

SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int nextPosition = random.nextInt(c);
    sb.append(alpha.charAt(nextPosition));
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

*While this works, I have a feeling that I'm wasting too much entrophy*. In this example, I'm asking the RNG *n* = 67 times for another number, and all of that just for generating one single `String`.

- Wouldn't it be more efficient (...entrophy saving) to call the RNG a
  much smaller amount of times and make better use of the returned
  values? E.g. calling the RNG only once with the method
  `nextBytes(byte[] bytes)` and a `byte` array just large enough to
  create a `String` of length 67?
- But in the latter case, I don't know how to map the random `byte`
  array to the desired `String`. It would be easy if one character had
  a size of one byte (or the multiple of one byte), so for *n* = 67 I
  could ask the RNG for 67 random `byte`s and then just map directly
  from each `byte` in the array to one character. However, with an alphabet of size *c* = 23, each character has only five bytes, without even making use of all the five bytes - if we enumerate all the characters from above, then the first character `'a'` has a binary value of `00000` whereas the last character `'w'` has a binary value of `10110` (it's not a coincidence that I've chosen prime numbers for *n* and *c*, it really should work in any case).

Comment: A not fully related note: replacing string builder by char array `char[]` with length `n` will be faster.

Comment: @MincongHuang true, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do some math: what's the smallest number `n` of bytes that we need to cover 67 characters from a 23-letter alphabet? Consider each byte a "letter" in a 256-letter alphabet. Then

23<sup>67</sup> < 256<sup>n</sup>

or

n > 67 * ln(23) / ln(256), which works out to 37.8848, or 38 bytes.

You can generate an array of 38 bytes, construct `BigInteger` from it, and call `divideAndRemainder(23)` 67 times to get individual character indexes and the next number in the iteration:

```
random.nextBytes(bytes);
BigInteger big = new BigInteger(bytes).abs();
BigInteger bigC = BigInteger.valueOf(c);
for (int i = 0 ; i != n ; i++) {
    BigInteger[] dr = big.divideAndRemainder(bigC);
    res[i] = alpha.charAt(dr[1].intValue());
    big = dr[0];
}
String result = new String(res);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/sqZqto)